# Array text manipulation

Tags: arrays, vb.net, text-manipulation

So, I've managed to populate an array with the names of directories, what i need to do now is remove certain parts of the directory names. this is what most of my array look like

```
F:\Users\Killu\AppData\Local\osu!\Songs\82734 Sakakibara Yui - Nyanderful!
```

what i need to remove is "F:\Users\Killu\AppData\Local\osu!\Songs\" and then everything after the number. so i would just be left with the various number in my array, the numbers do vary in length from 1 to 7 digits

Comment: Try something like this [Path.GetFileName Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx). And then remove the leading numbers, by replacing or what ever.

Answer (score 0):

Use split then connect them together again

```
Dim Result as string
Dim splitdir() as string = Split("F:\Users\Killu\AppData\Local\osu!\Songs\82734 Sakakibara Yui - Nyanderful!", "\")
Dim x as integer
For i as integer = 0 to 99
For j as integer = 0 to 9
If splitdir(i).substring(0,1) = j
x = i
i = 99
End if
Next
Next

For i as integer = x to splitdir.length - 1
Result += splitdir(i)
Next
```

Or if the numbers are always in the last part of the directory

```
Dim Result as string
Dim splitdir() as string = Split("F:\Users\Killu\AppData\Local\osu!\Songs\82734 Sakakibara Yui - Nyanderful!", "\")
Dim x as integer
Result = splitdir(splitdir.length - 1)
```

I was typing this on my ipad so im sorry if i made some typos/mistakes